# Why is my curve modifier not working?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, transforms, scale, bezier-curves

I want the mesh to follow the curve and to bend accordingly without any distortion. So far absolute failure... My teeth mesh just won't follow the curve, instead it gets stretched on an axis  and becomes 2d flat ... Both the mesh and the curve have the same origin point, both have origin set to volume (someone here apparently solved similar problem by doing this, didnt work). I tried with constraints to get the same effect same fail attempt. I just want simply my mesh to follow the curve and bend but it doesn't work. If someone have a solution to my problem I'll be grateful. Thanks.

[Before I apply the modifiers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg9IH.png)

[image: After I apply them mesh just becomes flat beyond recognition]

[image]

Comment: It looks like your mesh is oriented in the wrong direction, so you maybe have to roate it in _Edit Mode_. But even then... teeth? Usually teeth are separate objects, and the _Curve Modifier_ will generate a continuous geometry of the mesh...

Answer (score 3):

What you could do:

Select your curve and in *Edit* mode select all, right click > *Set Curve Radius* > 1 (you must have applied the scale of your curve, it has lowered the vertices radius down to 0.04).

Rotate your teeth until they are aligned with the global axis, apply the scale and the rotation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, right click > *Origin to Geometry*:

[image]

Give it the *Array* modifier with the *Fit Type > Fit Curve* and *Relative Offset > Factor X > 1*:

[image]

Give it the *Curve* modifier with the good *Deform Axis* (for me, X):

[image]

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for looking it up for me I solved it earlier by just starting from scratch and not messing up the rotations and scale of the object, but your answer clears things up. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

To make an object with array modifier follow a curve correctly...

1. the object should have applied scale and rotation (your scale is not applied)
2. both, object and curve should have location/origin at 0,0,0 (yours both haven't that

-> then it works.

Comment: Solved. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to make it a one-piece mesh, which is not difficult when you know the number of elements, and apply only Curve modif as it works best with continuous meshes. One-piece meshes have, too, this avantage over arrayed/combined ones their elements don't need to be separated for editing.

Answer (score 0):

Your teeth mesh its geting stretched and becoming 2d flat because you scaled the  curve in object mode and then applied it. If un want to scale the curve, do it in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing the axis to the xy front view worked when I used a Bezier curve.